# Changing Speakerconfiguration via VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, audio

To understand my problem I have to tell you my soundconfiguration right now.
I use a Creative Audigy SE which supports 7.1 Sound. So I pluged in my headset to the first connector and my speakers to the second which now gives me a 4.1 Soundsystem. The speakers are there to watch movies when I'm in bed and the headset is for normal computer-use (games etc.). Now I configured the driver that the speakers play the same as the headset and for the media stuff this works great, but when i start a game, the game seems to use my setup as a normal 4.1 system ignoring my system-configuration. In some games you can manually set it up right, but not in all. So my idea is to write a small proggram which let me fast switch between 2.1 for games and 4.1 for media-stuff and here comes the problem.

Is there any way in VB.Net to change the current sound-setting from 2.1 to 4.1? (I'm using Win 7 if that is important!)

Answer (score 0):

There's a featured program on [this site](http://mysite.verizon.net/teridon/hacks/index.html). You could perhaps use the DirectShow.Net project also?